# How do I implement the Page Object Pattern C# Code described below with selenium?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I need to implement the following Page Object Pattern C# Code with selenium. https://www.automatetheplanet.com/page-object-pattern/

Inside one of the examples; there is some code-

```
   [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "sb_form_q")]
    public IWebElement SearchBox { get; set; }
```

If I were to run some tests with the following code how would I use the code pattern with id, classes, values from a website. etc? Can someone give examples?

Comment: You want examples of different locator strategies?

Comment: yes please.....

Comment: To be clear, this is not the page object pattern you are asking about. It's PageFactory attributes. See [the docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_PageObjects_FindsByAttribute.htm). BTW, the Selenium contributors recommend NOT using PageFactory. It was written as example code of things you can do, not intended for people to actually use. See Simon Stewart, lead committer, state this [here](https://youtu.be/gyfUpOysIF8?t=25m17s).

Comment: @JeffC Seems you haven't understood the sarcasm Simon presented. Hold on your horses till 27m:50s. Regarding PageFactory, Simon clearly says "I love this stuff, it's good"

Comment: @DebanjanB No. If you think he's being sarcastic, you don't understand sarcasm and are trying too hard to justify using PageFactory or just don't understand English that well. It's not even three minutes long... watch it again. Go watch his other videos, they're full of him and others saying don't use this stuff.

Comment: @JeffC As you haven't worked with PageFactory ever, it's fine if you are still assuming PageFactory is not a good option but please don't mislead the entire community based on your lack of knowledge. At the minimum, get your basic facts right, Simon is not only the _lead committer_ but the **creater** of _WebDriver_.

Comment: I am having so much trouble with creating selenium tests in VS with C#. Im on a mac so what sort of file do I need to create? Is it a xUNit test project file? or a generic file? ??

Comment: @DebanjanB I'm not assuming PageFactory is not a good option... I'm listening to Simon, the lead committer on the Selenium project, state that it shouldn't be used, heeding his advice, and pointing others to what he said by linking to the yt video. You're the only one misleading everyone by ignoring what he said and telling others to do the same. I never said he was "only" anything... and it's "creator", not "creater". I just said you (and others) should heed his advice given his position and experience.

Comment: @JeffC This would be my last effort to suggest you that you need to understand the way how Simon was trying to address the issues users (might) faces with _PageObjects_. There are a lot many videos on _PageObjects_ by Simon. Go through them with patience. Hopefully you will discover the replies to all of your question on _PageObjects_. Feel free to raise your question here, stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: @DebanjanB I was there in the audience when Simon did that talk in Austin at SeleniumConf last year. I understand what he was saying... Don't use PageFactory (amongst a lot of other things). You can continue to believe what you want. Take your own advice and watch it again with patience... or you could come onto the Selenium Discord channel and ask him for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**Page Object Pattern Locators in C# -**

1) By ID -

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "your id")]
        public IWebElement my_ID_Element{ get; set; }
```

2) By Name -

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "your_name")]
        public IWebElement my_Name_Element{ get; set; }
```

3) By Xpath -

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//your_xpath")]
        public IWebElement my_Xpath_Element{ get; set; }
```

4) By CSS Selector -

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "your_css_selector")]
        private IWebElement my_CSS_Selector_Element;
```

5) By Class Name -

```
[FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "your_class_name")]
        private IWebElement my_Class_Name_Element;
```